# Center two divs in the center of another div and include margin between them

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center two divs horizontally in another div and have a max width defined for each. I'd also like there to be some space in between the divs so they are not touching.

The code below does not do what I was expecting:

HTML:

```
<div class="thing" id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <h2>Heading!</h2>
    <p>Words</p>
    <p>More words</p>
  </div>
  <div class="polaroid">
    <p>Words</p>
    <img src="path to image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thing {
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 3vh 1vw;
}

#outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

#inner {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: justify;
  /* float: left; */
  height: 422px;
}

.polaroid {
  position: relative;
  /* width: 50%;
  max-width: 350px; */
  /* float:left; */
}

.polaroid img {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  width: 50vw;
  max-width: 450px;
}

.polaroid p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flex grid

```
 #outer{

 display:flex;
 }
```

[Here is the live example](https://jsfiddle.net/2ffhwv8x/1/)

Comment: Thank you! I also had to add "justify-content: center" to #outer

Comment: yeah but flex is the best way now a day !

Comment: Oddly enough, this also popped the paragraph showing under the polaroid image outside of the box.

Answer (score 0):

change the width of one inner div and give a margin as necessary

```
.thing {
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 3vh 1vw;
  background-color:#f00;
}

#outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

#inner {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: justify;
  float: left; 
  height: 422px;
  background-color:#0f0;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.polaroid {
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
  max-width: 350px; 
   float:left; 
}

.polaroid img {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  width: 50vw;
  max-width: 450px;
}

.polaroid p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/mszaju6f/

```css
.thing {
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 3vh 1vw;
}

#outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

#inner {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: justify;
  /* float: left; */
  height: 422px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.polaroid {
  position: relative;
  /* width: 50%;
  max-width: 350px; */
  /* float:left; */
  display:inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.polaroid img {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  width: 50vw;
  max-width: 450px;
}

.polaroid p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing" id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <h2>Heading!</h2>
    <p>Words</p>
    <p>More words</p>
  </div>
  <div class="polaroid">
    <p>Words</p>
    <img src="path to image" />
  </div>
</div>
```